# Limit the scaling of pinch gesture method to the height of screen

Tags: swift, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have two background images: background.png (1920 x 1280) and background@2x.png (3840 x 2560). Also, app works only on landscape mode.

At run time the size of my background image is at its max.

PROBLEM: I try to print to the console the height and with of my background image using the pinch gesture method but on each print, both values remain at 4001.999.. x 2668.0, even though, the size of my background image does gets resize while pinching in and out.

What I'm trying to accomplish is: Access the width and height of my SKSpriteNode containing my background image so that I can check if its height is equal to that of the screen. If it is, it disables the effect of the pinch gesture of further zoom in. I would also like to manage the same effect but for zooming out.

If someone can suggest a better algorithm for doing this, please, feel free to share. Thanks!!

This is my code:

```
    // Background
    backgroundNode = createBackground()
    self.addChild(backgroundNode)
    println("anchorPoint = \(self.anchorPoint)")

}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("pinchView:"))
    pinchRecognizer.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecognizer)

}

// NODES

func createBackground() -> SKNode {

    let backgroundNode = SKNode()
    let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background/background")
    node.name = "bg"
    node.setScale(scaleFactor)

    backgroundNode.addChild(node)

    return backgroundNode

}

// GESTURES

func pinchView(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    let minScale: CGFloat = 0.15
    let maxScale: CGFloat = 3
    let tempScale = backgroundNode.xScale * sender.scale

    let pinch: SKAction = SKAction.scaleBy(sender.scale, duration: 0.0)

    if tempScale > minScale && tempScale < maxScale {

        backgroundNode.runAction(pinch)
        sender.scale = 1.0

    }

    var width = backgroundNode.childNodeWithName("bg")?.self.frame.size.width
    var height = backgroundNode.childNodeWithName("bg")?.self.frame.size.height
        println("width: \(width)") // 4001.999...
        println("height: \(height)") // 2668.0

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if touches.count == 1 {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let prevLoc: CGPoint = touch.previousLocationInView(view)
            let curentLoc: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(view)

            let deltaX: CGFloat = curentLoc.x - prevLoc.x
            let deltaY: CGFloat = curentLoc.y - prevLoc.y

            backgroundNode.position.x += deltaX
            backgroundNode.position.y -= deltaY

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're getting a scaling effect, but the size of the sprite node is not changing.  This appears to be because you're scaling the sprite's parent node rather than the sprite itself.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to scale the background image. If I change the width and height in pinchView method to: var width = backgroundNode.frame.size.width, var height = backgroundNode.frame.size.height, the result is 0.0 for every print. I'm very confused about this. I have a SKNode backgroundNode that contains the SKSpriteNode node that has the image 'background'. Why are these values so off?

Comment: Look at "Characteristics of Nodes" in the SKNode documentation for a discussion of a node's frame. Your background node doesn't itself have any visual content, so its frame size will remain (0, 0) (see also calculateAccumulatedFrame). It's the sprite that has content; try scaling it instead and see if its size doesn't update accordingly.

Comment: @kevinOwens thanks for your help. I assumed that if I scaled the parent node, the child node's width and height would be changed as well. I've fixed it and is working better now. :)

Comment: You're welcome ... something I learned through my own trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer discussed in the comments to the question is to scale the sprite node itself, rather than its parent `SKNode`.  Since the `SKNode` does not have any visual content (see [Apple's discussion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/) of the `SKNode`'s `frame` property under "Characteristics of Nodes"), its frame size will be `(width: 0, height: 0)`.  Note that should you need the bounding rectangle for all visual nodes within an `SKNode`, the `calculateAccumulatedFrame()` method is available.